# Log4j CVE-2021-44228 - vulnerability in MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding the Log4j vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228) in some of my MySQL hosts.
Even though I see it is not installed by MySQL,  wanted to confirm if MySQL uses this package anyway for any of its feature.

Is there a way to find out the list of applications that use a specific rpm package in RHEL?

If there is no dependency with MySQL, I can check with the application team for the fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Your friends are probably `apt depends <package-name>` and `apt rdepends <package-name>`.

Running an `apt depends mysql-server` will start rolling up from MySQL:

```
root@servername:~# apt depends mysql-server
mysql-server
  Depends: mysql-server-5.7
```

Running the same for `mysql-server-5.7` produces:

```
root@servername:~# apt depends mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7
  PreDepends: adduser (>= 3.40)
  PreDepends: debconf
  PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
  Depends: bsdutils
    bsdutils:i386
  Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.0-10)
  Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
  Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)
  Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
  Depends: passwd
    passwd:i386
  Depends: perl (>= 5.6)
  Depends: psmisc
    psmisc:i386
 |Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: <debconf-2.0>
    cdebconf
    debconf
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libevent-core-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0)
  Depends: liblz4-1 (>= 0.0~r127)
  Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
  Conflicts: <mysql-client-5.5>
  Conflicts: <mysql-server-5.5>
  Conflicts: <virtual-mysql-server>
    percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
    mariadb-server-10.1
  Breaks: <mysql-server-5.6> (<< 5.7)
  Recommends: libhtml-template-perl
  Suggests: <mailx>
    bsd-mailx
    mailutils
  Suggests: tinyca
  Replaces: <mysql-client-5.5>
  Replaces: <mysql-server-5.5>
  Replaces: <mysql-server-5.6> (<< 5.7)
  Replaces: <virtual-mysql-server>
    percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
    mariadb-server-10.1
    mysql-server-5.7
```

So at first sight nothing there that would suggest that `log4j` is involved.

Let's try a reverse lookup using the syntax `apt rdepends <package-name>`:

```
root@servername:~# apt rdepends mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: mysql-testsuite-5.7 (= 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
  Depends: mysql-server
  Replaces: percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
  Breaks: percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
  Depends: mysql-testsuite-5.7 (= 5.7.21-1ubuntu1)
  Conflicts: mariadb-server-core-10.1
  Replaces: mariadb-server-10.1
  Breaks: mariadb-server-10.1
  Depends: mysql-server
 |Depends: mythtv-backend-master
 |Depends: mythtv
  Replaces: percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
  Breaks: percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
  Depends: mysql-server
  Conflicts: mariadb-server-core-10.1
  Replaces: mariadb-server-10.1
  Breaks: mariadb-server-10.1
  Depends: default-mysql-server
```

Nothing there. So let's do the same for `log4j` with depends:

```
root@servername:~# apt depends *log4j*
liblog4j1.2-java
  Suggests: liblog4j1.2-java-doc
  Suggests: libmail-java
liblog4j2-java
  Depends: liblightcouch-java
  Depends: libmongodb-java
  Suggests: liblog4j2-java-doc
  Suggests: libcommons-compress-java
  Suggests: libcommons-csv-java (>= 1.5)
  Suggests: libconversant-disruptor-java (>= 1.2.11)
  Suggests: libdisruptor-java (>= 3.3.7)
  Suggests: libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java
  Suggests: libjackson2-core-java (>= 2.9.4)
  Suggests: libjackson2-databind-java
  Suggests: libjackson2-dataformat-xml-java
  Suggests: libjackson2-dataformat-yaml (>= 2.8.10)
  Suggests: libjansi-java (>= 1.16)
  Suggests: libjcommander-java
  Suggests: libjctools-java
  Suggests: libjeromq-java
  Suggests: libjpa-2.1-spec-java (>= 2.1.0)
  Suggests: libmail-java (>= 1.6.1)
  Suggests: libwoodstox-java (>= 4.1.3)
liblog4j1.2-java-doc
  Depends: default-jdk-doc
liblog4j-extras1.2-java
  Depends: libapache-pom-java (>= 18)
  Depends: liblog4j1.2-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Suggests: libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java
  Suggests: liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
  Recommends: default-jdk-doc
  Recommends: liblog4j1.2-java-doc
  Suggests: liblog4j-extras1.2-java
liblog4j2-java-doc
  Depends: default-jdk-doc
  Suggests: liblog4j2-java
node-log4js
  Depends: nodejs (>= 0.10.0)
  Depends: node-async (>= 0.1.15)
```

Looking good. And the reverse depends with `rdepends` looks good too:

```
root@servername:~# apt rdepends *log4j*
liblog4j1.2-java
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: libzookeeper-java (>> 1.2.15-8)
  Depends: mobile-atlas-creator
  Recommends: libuima-core-java
  Depends: libthrift-java
  Suggests: libspring-core-java
  Depends: libresteasy3.0-java
  Suggests: libquartz-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libopenjpa-java
  Suggests: libnetty-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Suggests: libnetty-3.9-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Recommends: liblucene3-contrib-java
  Depends: libjaxe-java
  Suggests: libc3p0-java
  Depends: libapacheds-java
  Depends: libapache-poi-java
  Depends: jftp
  Suggests: ant-optional
  Depends: activemq
  Depends: jajuk
  Depends: igv
  Depends: umlet
  Depends: pegasus-wms
  Depends: natbraille
  Depends: mobile-atlas-creator
  Depends: logol
  Depends: libdoxia-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Suggests: libxbean-reflect-java
  Suggests: libxbean-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libvamsas-client-java
  Recommends: libuima-core-java
  Depends: libuima-as-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libuima-addons-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libthrift-java
  Suggests: libspring-core-java
  Suggests: libslf4j-java
  Suggests: libquartz-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libowasp-esapi-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libopsin-java
  Depends: libopenjpa-java
  Suggests: libopenid4java-java
  Suggests: libnetty-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Suggests: libnetty-3.9-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libmpj-java
  Depends: libmime-util-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libmavibot-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Recommends: liblucene3-contrib-java
  Depends: liblttng-ust-agent-java
  Depends: liblog4j-extras1.2-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Suggests: libjgroups-java
  Depends: libjglobus-ssl-proxies-java
  Recommends: libjenkins-json-java (>= 1.2.17)
  Depends: libjaxe-java
  Depends: libjas-java
  Depends: libjaba-client-java
  Depends: libgradle-android-plugin-java
  Depends: libgmetrics-groovy-java
  Depends: libexcalibur-logkit-java
  Depends: libexcalibur-logger-java
  Depends: eclipse-wtp-ws (>= 1.2.17-7ubuntu1)
  Suggests: libcommons-logging-java
  Depends: libcodenarc-groovy-java
  Depends: libcdk-java
  Suggests: libc3p0-java
  Depends: libapache-poi-java
  Depends: jftp
  Depends: jets3t
  Depends: jalview
  Depends: iamcli
  Depends: eclipse-wtp-xsl (>= 1.2.17-7ubuntu1)
  Depends: activemq
  Depends: davmail
  Depends: artemis
  Suggests: ant-optional
liblog4j2-java
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: libnetty-java (>= 2.10.0)
 |Depends: jabref (>= 2.10.0-2)
  Depends: jabref (<< 2.10)
 |Depends: jabref (>= 2.10.0-2)
  Suggests: libnetty-java (>= 2.8.2)
  Suggests: liblog4j2-java-doc
  Depends: libbiojava4.0-java
  Depends: jabref (<< 2.10)
liblog4j1.2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: libdoxia-java-doc
  Suggests: liblog4j1.2-java
  Depends: libowasp-esapi-java-doc
  Suggests: liblog4j1.2-java
  Recommends: liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
  Recommends: libjenkins-json-java-doc
  Recommends: libfreemarker-java-doc
liblog4j-extras1.2-java
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: liblog4j-extras1.2-java
liblog4j2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: liblog4j2-java
node-log4js
Reverse Depends:
```

Even if I compare the results of the outputs with each other I can't find an overlapping dependency.

Limiting the output to packages that are `--installed` on a given server will further reduces the output to one page:

```
root@servername:~# apt depends *log4j* --installed
liblog4j1.2-java
liblog4j2-java
liblog4j1.2-java-doc
liblog4j-extras1.2-java
liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
liblog4j2-java-doc
node-log4js

root@servername:~# apt rdepends *log4j* --installed
liblog4j1.2-java
Reverse Depends:
liblog4j2-java
Reverse Depends:
liblog4j1.2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
liblog4j-extras1.2-java
Reverse Depends:
liblog4j-extras1.2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
liblog4j2-java-doc
Reverse Depends:
node-log4js
Reverse Depends:

root@servername:~# apt rdepends *mysql-server-5.7* --installed
mysql-server-5.7
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: mysql-server
  Depends: mysql-server
  Depends: mysql-server

root@servername:~# apt depends *mysql-server-5.7* --installed
mysql-server-5.7
  PreDepends: adduser (>= 3.40)
  PreDepends: debconf
  PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
  Depends: bsdutils
    bsdutils:i386
  Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.0-10)
  Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
  Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)
  Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
  Depends: passwd
    passwd:i386
  Depends: perl (>= 5.6)
  Depends: psmisc
    psmisc:i386
 |Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
    cdebconf
    debconf
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libevent-core-2.1-6 (>= 2.1.8-stable)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0)
  Depends: liblz4-1 (>= 0.0~r127)
  Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
    percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
    mariadb-server-10.1
  Recommends: libhtml-template-perl
    bsd-mailx
    mailutils
    percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
    mariadb-server-10.1
    mysql-server-5.7
```

Your mileage/outcome may vary. We are using MySQL on standard Ubuntu with no GUI like Gnome or the likes. So we only have CLI to manipulate the MySQL instances.

Comment: Thanks John.. that gave very good insights. I tried couple of commands in RHEL and i dont think MySQL has a dependency on Log4j . Not able to post complete dependency tree due to character limitation here, but i dont see MySQL there
                                                                 

repoquery  --pkgnarrow=installed --tree-whatrequires log4j-1.2.17-16.el7_4.noarch

log4j-0:1.2.17-16.el7_4.noarch [cmd line]
 \_  apache-commons-logging-0:1.1.2-7.el7.noarch [1: mvn(log4j:log4j) = 1.2.17]
 |   \_  avalon-framework-0:4.3-10.el7.noarch [1: apache-commons-logging = 1.1.2-7.el7]

Comment: If there is any relation between mysql and log4j, it might be from some application written in java, eg through some GU Interface (Workbench, etc). Check if there is any such installed on your server.

Comment: I doubt we have MySQL workbench on Linux hosts. we usually have it only in our Windows implementation. Let me check that as well. Thanks for your time @ypercube

Comment: I didn't mean only Workbench but any GUI or other admin tool. I don't even know if workbench is written in java.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - it's [mostly written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849568/whats-the-underlying-technology-behind-mysql-workbench-gui/21874267#21874267) in C++ with some Python for scripting and whatnot - Mike Lischke is the primary author and current Oracle/MySQL [project manager](https://github.com/mike-lischke). FYI!

Comment: For debian systems look at apt-rdepends (separate tool). Gives a much more succinct and understandable output.

Comment: Honestly, this cannot guarantee a webserver is not using Log4J.  You could have a war or jar file that has packed log4j inside of it (very common) and is deployed on a tomcat server or other java based web service.  You could search the file system and find nothing.

Comment: I don't think the question is about a webserver.

Answer (score 9):

MySQL Server is written in C++, not Java, so it does not use Log4j. The same is true of MySQL Workbench.

In fact, see in https://github.com/orgs/mysql/repositories?type=all
that
MySQL Connector/J is the only MySQL product written in Java.

But according to the [release notes for version 5.1.15](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-15.html) (2011-02-09), it does not include Log4j. It was removed long ago to satisfy license conditions.

It is possible that you integrated Log4j yourself, because the release notes mention that the current log implementation may be plugged into Log4j. But you must know whether you did that or not.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Bill